# Flutter apk installation package conflict

Tags: android, flutter, installation, apk

I recently had to change my SSD drive. I got my Flutter android apps from backup and now I've created new update for one of my apps, but when I tried to install this update, I got 'App not installed as package conflicts with an existing package' error.
The fix is simple, just uninstall existing app and install new one, right?
Unfortunately, this app holds a lot of data locally in app's folder and users would lose everything if they uninstall the app.
I read that now my app has different signature, something like that.
Is there any way to repair the signature of my app, so the phone would see the updated APK as the same app that is already installed and not as another app with the same name?

I tried uninstalling the app and then installing the updated one and it worked of course, but I can't allow users to lose their data, so I need another solution without uninstalling the old version.

Comment: You also need to restore the signing key in the keystore you use for signing the app. If you have not created an own keystore in project folder then most likely it is in the `.android` folder in your home folder. Check your backup and restore the keystore.